# i have 9 edit text for user input to take data in one activity and want to show them in the listview in another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i have 9 edit texts in one activity and it takes user inputs within certain time..if the user fills them within certain time i have to populate them to the listviw in another activity....and from the listview of another activity..i have to get the same edittexts ...here is the xml view of first activity...

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="2."
    tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="3."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="5."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText6"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="4."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="6."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText7"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="7."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="8."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="9."
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="1."
    tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="finish" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the listview activity..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="search saved session"
    tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" >

</SearchView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView1" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="saved"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchView1"
    android:text="about"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="new session"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i have tried using sqlite....is it better to use sqlite or shared preferences?i have to add search functionality to the displayed list alos.....

Comment: @laalto: how can i perform such behavoir??i am new to android and cant think of idea ..how to do and what to use??